# Not able to create a new line in my string

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Just started day 2 of migrating from Java to Ruby. My code is quite trivial, I want to print a 9x9 grid but when I go through my nested for loop I can't create a new line termination. Please let me know what I'm missing here, thanks!

```
table = ""
for i in 1...10 do
  for j in 1...10 do
    table += j.to_s 
  end
  table += "\n"
end
```

And, here is the result:

```
2.1.0 :078 > table
 => "123456789\n123456789\n123456789\n123456789\n123456789\n123456789\n123456789\n123456789\n123456789\n"
```

Comment: Your question is not clear. Does Arup's answer answer your question?

Comment: A more concise way is `[(1...10).to_a.join].*(9).join("\n")`.

Comment: @sawa, yes, Arup did answer my question

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You just need to write as `puts table`. See the method [`Kernel#puts`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.0/Kernel.html#method-i-puts)

```
table = ""

for i in 1...10 do
  for j in 1...10 do
    table += j.to_s 
  end
  table += "\n"
end
puts table

# >> 123456789
# >> 123456789
# >> 123456789
# >> 123456789
# >> 123456789
# >> 123456789
# >> 123456789
# >> 123456789
# >> 123456789
```

A more Ruby way as an example(9X9):

```
a = Array.new(9,[*1..9]).map(&:join)
puts a
# >> 123456789
# >> 123456789
# >> 123456789
# >> 123456789
# >> 123456789
# >> 123456789
# >> 123456789
# >> 123456789
# >> 123456789
```

Look the documentation :- [`Array::new`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.0/Array.html#method-c-new)

Comment: Thanks, I knew it was something simple.

Answer (score 2):

Behold the magestic power of ruby!!!

```
puts ([*1..9].join + "\n")*9
```

Comment: It got some getting used to but I'm really beginning to love the simplicity of Ruby